# How to pass Inbuilt stack as reference to a recursive function in c++

Tags: c++, reference

I have to reverse the stack recursively.
using the same stack.

```
void reverse(stack<int> *s)
{

  if(s->empty())
    return;
 int element= s->top();
  s->pop();
  reverse(s);
  s->push(element);

}
```

Comment: `void reverse(stack<int>& s)`

Comment: I don't see, what is your problem. The algorithm or syntax of C++ using pointers/references?

Comment: Your biggest issue is that your stack isn't reversed by the reverse() function. Face it: going down the stack popping the elements and then reversely pushing them results in the same stack.  If you want a solution for this, then that is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure is that possible with LIFO structures, in your code you remove one from top then put it on top, makes no sense, might work using array or another stack as parametar. In order to put something on first position stack need to be empty or you can implement method PushAtBottom but it won't be stack anymore I guess, and you will need to use your own stack.

Example:

```
#include<iostream>
template<class s>
class stack
{
        int top;
        s* Array;
        int counter;
public:
    stack(){
        top = 0;
        Array = new s[10];
        counter = 0;
    }
    s Pop(){
        if(top!=0){
            s rTop = Array[top];
            Array[top] = NULL;
            top--;
            return rTop;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    void Push(s item){
        top++;
        Array[top] = item;
    }
    void PushAtBottom(s item){
        for(int i=top;i>counter;i--)
        {
            Array[i+1] = Array[i]; 
        }
        Array[++counter] = item;
        top++;
    }
    bool empty(){
        if(top!=0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    bool reverse_done(){ //funtion that stops recursion
        if(counter >= top)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

void stack_reverse(stack<int> *s){
    if(s->reverse_done())
        return;
    s->PushAtBottom(s->Pop());
    stack_reverse(s);

}

void main(){

    stack<int> * s = new stack<int>();
    s->Push(1);
    s->Push(2);
    s->Push(3);
    stack_reverse(s);
    std::cout << s->Pop();
    std::cout << s->Pop();
    std::cout << s->Pop();
}
```

Comment: @wedo thanks!! i get what i want , it is really helpful.